# Filling Two Columns Automatically

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create two column layout for my list using CSS.

Let's say I have 5 items, the presentation would be:

```
<item 1>  <item 4>
<item 2>  <item 5>
<item 3>
```

How can I do this with HTML and CSS? Keep in mind that the list length is variable.

I'll be generating the HTML server side using C#, that will provide more flexibility.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using CSS, sounds more like a javascript/JSP solution you are needing

Comment: Yes, silly, I'll be generating the HTML and CSS server side. I'd like to know what the HTML and CSS will look like.

Comment: Across is easier, down is harder... There are some tricks, but mostly, the "newspaper columns" effect is considered hard in css. There are some extensions to css which do it, though they're not cross browser...

Comment: e.g. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns

Comment: @Adrian: I agree; I offered that link as evidence of "not possible without proprietary effects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made up my mind and use two floated DIVs to achieve this layout.

The server side code will iterate the items and create a new DIV if it passes the halfway point (current index >= half of length).

The resulting HTML would look like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column { float: left; }
```

The server side will determine when to close and create a new DIV. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: And your code would be..? The point of Stackoverflow is to help others by posting code solutions. I'm glad that you were able to answer/solve your own problem, but it'd be nice if you could help out others that might come across the same problem in future =)